Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Resgatar" no matter what I try with Selenium
The button click "Resgatar" with Selenium  used to work until just yesterday. Site is: https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/titulos/precos-e-taxas.htm.
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
options = Options()
options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/alvaro/downloads/chromedriver2',options=options)
browser.get('https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/titulos/precos-e-taxas.htm') 
link = browser.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,"Resgatar")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link)

I've tried WebDriverWait and it did not solve the problem. By.CLASS_NAME neither. Any ideas?
It is a huge html, 5k lines+. Check it out on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/vBD1mVd2. Here goes the code around the button:
<div class="td-precosTaxas-wrapper">
<div class="td-tabs td-precosTaxas-tabs">
    <div class="td-precosTaxas-tabs__content">
        <ul class="td-tabs-precos_taxas-links td-tabs-links td-internal-wrapper--no-mobile" data-tabgroup="td-precos_taxas-tab-group">
            <li class="td-tabs-links__item">
                <a class="td-tabs-links__link active" role="button" href="#td-precos_taxas-tab_1">
                    Investir
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="td-tabs-links__item">
                <a class="td-tabs-links__link td-link-tab-2" role="button" href="#td-precos_taxas-tab_2">
                    Resgatar
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

I have also tried:
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
options = Options()
options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/alvaro/downloads/chromedriver2',options=options)
browser.get('tesourodireto.com.br/titulos/precos-e-taxas.htm') 
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'Resgatar')]"))).click()

The result was: TimeoutException

Maybe the website was updated, and the button has different text now?

The button text remains the same. I have refreshed again and again.

Can you post the html code for that element?

RESGATAR is not the same as Resgatar.

Both RESGATAR (as it shows to end user) and Resgatar do not work - and it used to, before some subtle change

"Resgatar" should work.  If it doesn't, then something else must be wrong.  Either the html is different from what you showed here, or the element has been moved inside a <frame> container, or any of a hundred other details that we cannot possibly guess.

If the button text really is displayed as RESGATAR, that suggests the html you showed is not accurate.  How exactly did you get that html?  From the browser "view source" command, from the browser "inspect element" command, or some other way?

Inside a  container is a good hypothesis. How could I check that? If you @JohnGordon may have look at https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/titulos/precos-e-taxas.htm you will see that "RESGATAR" is a big central button and we may dig deeper

View the page html source, look for a frame element, and see if the button is contained inside of it.

I could not find it to be on a frame element. "Frame" only appears once on the full html, up in the header

Did you look for the <frame> tag specifically?  There are also other similar tags, such as <iframe>.

Up high on the html: 

Okay, so it looks like a frame isn't the issue.  The problem must be something else, and there are dozens, if not hundreds, of possibilities.  From the details you have given, we can't tell what the problem is.  (Although I see that you have not updated the python code sample to use "Resgatar" instead of "RESGATAR"...)

Same error both with "Resgatar" and "RESGATAR"

What else could it be @undetected Selenium?

If you showed us the full code, and the full html, maybe we could find the problem.  Without that, we are just guessing.

Code would not be a problem, but html from this public site is 5k lines long

Whole code just published at the question

I don't see anything obvious wrong with the code.  I can't test it, though, because that website apparently blocks access for north american IP addresses.  Can you save the html text and upload it to a pastebin?

Html on pastbin: https://pastebin.com/vBD1mVd2

Can you show how you tried to use WebDriverWait?

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
options = Options()
options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/alvaro/downloads/chromedriver2',options=options)
browser.get('https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/titulos/precos-e-taxas.htm')
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'Resgatar')]"))).click()
Result: TimeoutException

It's very hard to read formatted code in a comment.  Can you post that in the question?

Chrome 128.0.6613.114 (oficial) (x86_64)

You can get the data from the API directly, but you'll need to install curl_cffi in order to bypass cloudflare protection:
pip install curl_cffi --upgrade

You can then use it like this:
from curl_cffi import requests

url = 'https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/json/br/com/b3/tesourodireto/service/api/treasurybondsinfo.json'
response = requests.get(url, impersonate='chrome')

data = response.json()
rows = data['response']['TrsrBdTradgList']

print(rows)


If you still want to use selenium, there is no need to click the 'Resgatar' button, the elements are already present in the dom:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/titulos/precos-e-taxas.htm')

rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#td-precos_taxas-tab_2 .td-invest-table__card')
print(len(rows))


Json is a great idea but it still does not work. Error is: impersonate chrome is not supported. I was using selenium until the site started blocking it. Your second block of code does not help for that reason

@AlMartins try using impersonate='chrome124' and make sure you have the latest version of curl_cffi (0.7.1)

@AlMartins is it still not working?

Back working using selenium on local but not via cloud (pythonanywhere)

@AlMartins are you using a paid version of pythonanywhere? the free trial has limitations.

Try Using:
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@href="#td-precos_taxas-tab_2"]')))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)

or you can use ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@href="#td-precos_taxas-tab_2"]')))

actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.move_to_element(btn).click().perform()

Hope this might help.

Another TimeoutException

Can you send the code and screenshot of the error

raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Try the below code, I have tested it in my machine and it works:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
browser.get("https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/titulos/precos-e-taxas.htm")
browser.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

# Use below line of code only if you see accept/reject cookies pop-up
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'Resgatar')]"))).click()
time.sleep(5)


Chrome is 127.0.6533.122 (Versão oficial) (x86_64)

@Shawn I only get time outs. Cloudflare (or some blocker) seems to be in place: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
